# Usage of pronouns in chapter VIII of Lingua latina per se illustrata

Tags: grammar-choice, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, pronouns, demonstrative-adjective

This excerpt comes from lines 138-139 of chapter VIII  of the 2003 edition of *Lingua latina per se illustrata*:

> *Quis* saccum portat? Servus saccum portat. *Quī* servus?
> Servus *quī* saccum portat est Syrus. *Is*/*ille* servus saccum portat.

In the right hand side of the page, there is the following explanation:

> *is* servus = *ille* servus

I believe there is an error in such explanation and this should be

> *is* = *ille* servus

because *is* is a pronoun that can indeed be replaced by *ille servus*. Is my interpretation correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Is servus" is not an error.

Latin "pronouns"* don't work like English pronouns. *Is* can be used by itself, but it can also be used adjectivally with a noun. The same goes for *ille, iste* and *hic.*

[Lewis and Short](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/is) covers this type of use in section B:

> Esp.
> 1 In connection with a noun: ea re, quia turpe sit, faciendum non esse, Cic. Off. 3, 13: ea res ut est Helvetiis enuntiata, etc., Caes. B. G. 1, 4: ne ob eam rem tribueret, etc., id. ib. 1, 13: flumen est Arar ... id flumen, etc., id. ib. 1, 12: sub id tempus, Liv. 43, 5, 3: ejus disputationis sententias memoriae mandavi, Cic. Lael. 1, 3: ante eam diem, id. Att. 2, 11, 2: ea tempestate, Sall. C. 36, 4: quam urbem is rex condidit, Plin. 6, 17, 21, § 61.—

"Is servus" and "ille servus" are not actually interchangeable in general, but both are grammatical.

*I put this in scare quotes because linguists often consider Latin to have no true third-person pronouns.

Comment: So *is*, *ea*, *id* can work as demonstrative adjectives?

Comment: @Charo [Correct](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/demonstrative-pronouns-paradigms). Demonstrative pronouns in Latin are also equally demonstrative adjectives.

Comment: @Charo, not only **is/ea/id**, but also **ille/-a/-ud**, **iste/-a/-ud**, **hic/haec/hoc**, etc.

Comment: Yes, of course, @KotobaTrilyNgian: I knew the demonstrative adjectives-pronouns you mention. But I didn't know that *is, ea, id* can also be used as demonstrative adjectives. I'm a beginner in Latin.